# AWS DMS - single replication instance for migrating multiple source databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

I have to migrate 3 different source databases (2 servers of SQL Servers) and one Oracle to S3 using AWS DMS. Can i use a single replication instance to migrate 3 different source databases to target S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,
You can do that .

One replication instance can be very well be used for multiple tasks .
Just be mindful about Storage and Memory .